# How to manage subdomain (DNS vs multiple Apache2 server)?

Tags: apache, dns

I have a question about managing subdomains and how to best configure DNS in an architecture where the subdomains are dispatched on several servers
I don't even know if it's possible so requests for clarification

DNS configuration :
* A 51.51.51.1
@ A 51.51.51.1

Domain: example.com
Sub-domain : sub1.example.com

There are 2 servers: 51.51.51.1, 51.51.51.2

How can we configure Apache on the 51.51.51.1 server so that a request like http://sub1.example.com is redirected to the 51.51.51.2 server, of course keeping the same source URL in the browser ?
Do we have to add a registration in the DNS for the sub-domain sub1 or can we do without and only modify the Apache configuration on the server 51.51.51.1 ?
Which is more effective ?

Comment: It looks like all you have to do is add another A record: `sub1    A    51.51.51.2`

Comment: Thanks for your answser !
I would have liked to avoid because complicated to modify DNS by scripts given my environment.
There is really no possibility by modifying only the Apache configuration?

Comment: "redirect" and "keep the same source url in browser" are two opposite things so you can't have both. If you can't change DNS, all you can do is create reverse proxy for sub1 in your apache which will forward traffic to `.2`, but then all traffic for `.2` will have to pass through `.1`